# Display rows based on column values asp repeater / gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, data-binding, repeater

I am using **VB.NET**

I get a datatable with the following columns

```
ID   DESC  Hyperlink COUNT
```

The count is either `0` or `1`

If the count is `0` I need to do a

```
NavigateUrl='<%#"~/Create.aspx?ID=" + Eval("ID")%>' Text="Create"
```

in the hyperlink column

I am not doing any explicit operations on the databind event. 
the way i am populating the repeater is:

```
rptrTask.DataSource = PpltDefGrid(Trim(v))
```

where the function is just getting a sql table at the moment

```
rptrTask.DataBind()
```

Can someone give me the inline code on how to do this? if not any idea on how can i do this via code behind (with an Example please)? I have tried a few  / Container.data methods.. but haven't been successful. Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: it doesnt display the hyperlink.. just need to display the rest of the col data then..

Comment: what is count? you are fetching it from database or it is in datatable/dataset

Comment: @Ansari, the count is just a value, i am not sure how that will affect the answer to the question.. but would appreciate a feedback

Comment: check my answer, let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am editing my answer, then in that case `RowDataBound` would be easy choice for you.

Modify your GridView like this:-

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
```

I have added `"OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"`

In your .aspx page you can write like this for `hyperlink`

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Count">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In your .aspx.vb page write like this:-

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            Dim HyperLink1 As HyperLink = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("HyperLink1"), HyperLink)
            If DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "COUNT") = "0" Then
                HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "~/Create.aspx?ID=" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ID")
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Hope this help.

Comment: hi, i see now the reason for your question about the count. the count is value returned by the sql which populates the repeater. So although what you have given is correct it does not satisfy my requirements for this instance.
The count is saved in a column and based on that value(either 0/1)  i need to display the hyperlink for that row. Hope that clarifies the doubt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RowDatBound() event of the gridview in code behind.

```
 protected void rptrTask_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
            HyperLink hl = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("hyperlinkID");
            if(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "COUNT") == "0")
            {
            hl.NavigateUrl = "~/Create.aspx?ID=" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ID");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I extract the logic to the variable (bShowURl) so as to enhance manintability.  Also additional check is placed to ensure the hyperlink exists.

```
Protected Sub yourGridview_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            Dim currentDataItem As yourDataItemDataType = e.Row.DataItem
            Dim bShowUrl = IIF(currentDataItem.ID = 0, True, False)

            If bShowUrl Then
                Dim hyperlink As HyperLink = CType(e.Row.FindControl("yourHyperlinkControlId"), HyperLink) 
                If hyperlink IsNot Nothing Then
                    hyperlink.NavigateUrl = "~/Create.aspx?ID=" + currentDataItem.ID.ToString()
                End If
            End If
        End If

End Sub
```